# Plot 3D set (or a domain of three-variable function)

Tags: plotting, sets

is there any way to plot a "3D set" of points subject to certain rules? For example, my task is to find maximum of some function of three variables which have to meet some conditions. Of course I can't use Plot3D and RegionFunction because I would need a 4D space. So I tried to plot only the constraints (where "z" would be a function of "x" and "y"): the constraints are 3x^2>2y^2+z^2 and x^2+y^2=1, and then I used

```
Plot3D[{Sqrt[3 x^2 - 2 y^2],-Sqrt[3 x^2 - 2 y^2]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x^2 + y^2 >= 1]]
```

But this isn't working for some reason - I get only a box without any plot, but even if it did work, it wouldn't be very helpful because the first contraint is inequality and not an equation. I hope I expressed myself correctly and comprehensibly, English is not my mother tongue. Any ideas how to solve my issue?

Comment: Very generically, there is a `RegioPlot3D` function and  you might be better off with a different parametrization (like polar) of your variables.

Comment: So I tried `RegionPlot3D` which I think would be an excellent way to plot what I need (I didn't know this function before). At first, when I used the given constraints, I did not get any result (only an empty box again) but then I tried to change the second constraint to inequality (`x^2+y^2<=1`) and everything worked fine. So I think the only problem is that `RegionPlot3D` is not able to deal with an equation in its argument. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you're trying to plot the set of points $(x,y,z)$ such that $3x^2>2y^2+z^2$ and $x^2+y^2=1$. Now `RegionPlot3D` only works for inequalities, while `ContourPlot3D` only works for equations. But you can use `ContourPlot3D` on the equation and supply it the inequality as a `RegionFunction`.

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 3 x^2 > 2 y^2 + z^2], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

You can even colour the plot with another function of $(x,y,z)$...

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x] Cos[y] Tan[z]
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 3 x^2 > 2 y^2 + z^2], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["LakeColors"][f[x, y, z]/2 + 1/2]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps `ContourPlot3D` is useful, with an expression for x, y, and z, plus added constraints?

```
ContourPlot3D[Sin[x] Cos[y] Tan[z], 
 {x, -Pi, Pi},
 {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 {z, -Pi, Pi},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, (x^2 > (2 y^2 + z^2 ))],
 AxesStyle -> White
 Background -> Black]
```

[image: what the hell is this supposed to be]